# Unpickling hazard

Tags: python, pickle

In the Documentation of the python3 pickle module it says:

"
The pickle module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source."

What is the risk of unpickling data from untrusted sources? Is the unpickling of untrusted data itself dangerous? Or is it only dangerous to use the unpickled object? So is it safe to unpickle untrusted data and then (before doing anything with the resulting object) proving wether it's a save object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle recreates objects by looking up callables (commonly classes, but really any callable) and calling them with fixed arguments. This means that unpickling may run *any* callable *anywhere*, with *any* arguments. Even if the relevant module hasn't been imported yet, pickle will gladly import it. It takes only a couple dozen characters to [execute `os.system`](http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure), for example. So you're screwed *before you even get an object back*.

Answer (score 2):

Unpickling a pickle amounts to executing arbitrary code.  An attacker can create a pickle which will execute system commands during unpickling.

Here's an example from [a good blog post on the topic](http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure):

> This clearly states that pickle is insecure. Many think this is because it can load classes other than what you expect and may trick you to run their functions. But the actual security risk is far more dangerous. **Unpickling can be exploited to execute arbitrary commands on your machine!**

Comment: @nadiaAlramli Is that post still up someplace?  The blog post is great, but the link bounces directly to your linkdin page

Answer (score 1):

The pickle format uses a full-blown virtual machine. If the code fed into the machine is controlled by an attacker, it can do things well beyond object serialization (including executing arbitrary OS commands).

For a discussion, see [Why Python Pickle is Insecure](http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure).