# How can I read the binary txt file using pickle in python?

Tags: python, pickle

**This is my code**

```
def unpickle(file):
    import pickle
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
    return dict

file = unpickle('./labels_test.txt')

print(file)
```

**This is the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/Codes/LabelMe/Demo.py", line 9, in <module>
file = unpickle('./labels_test.txt')
File "D:/Codes/LabelMe/Demo.py", line 4, in unpickle
  .  dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
_pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow
```

**Appreciate it!**
When I open the txt file, it's just some symbols that I do not understand, so I guess it's a binary file, but I can't find a way to decode it using pickle in python...

Comment: Unpickle can only parse previously pickled files.

Comment: If it's actually pickled data, the file may be damaged. Depending on the first byte(s) of the file, damaged data might result in ```unpickling stack underflow``` or an error like ```_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x04'.```

Comment: Oh, and definitely take into account [Unpickling hazard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718667/unpickling-hazard)